# Obtener datos de td de tabla dinamica seleccionando boton

Tags: php, html, jquery

tengo un problema con una tabla dinámica, lo que quiero es obtener los valores de las celdas al hacer clic sobre el boton, por ejemplo en la primera celda esta el valor del rut al hacer clic obtener ese rut, etc.

```
$('.tablita3').on('click', '.btn-eliminar', function(){
    rut = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
    alert(rut);
});
```

ese es el codigo que tengo y esto es lo que me devuelve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo de tabla y llenado de esta

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-stripe white tablita3">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">RUT</th>
        <th width="15%">NOMBRE</th>
        <th width="10%">PATERNO</th>
        <th width="10%">MATERNO</th>
        <th width="10%">TIPO</th>
        <th width="10%">PERSONA</th>
        <th width="15%">ESTADO</th>
        <th width="10%">VIGENCIA</th>
        <th width="5%">MOD</th>
        <th width="5%">ELI</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tablita">
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['rut']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['paterno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['materno']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['titular']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['persona']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['estado']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['vigencia']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" style="height:25px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px;"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-eliminar" style="height:25px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px;"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

El método closest lo que hace es traer toda la herencia del elemento seleccionado de derecha a izquierda.

PORCIERTO no deberias seguir usando classes botones, ya que son obsoletas, puedes usar '>input type = botton value= "editar"<'

```
    $('#data-user ').on('click', ' tr #edit', function (e) {
         alert('YA ENTRO')
         e.preventDefault();
         var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
         editFOO(currentRow);
    });
```

La función editFOO

```
function editFOO(currentRow) {
alert('YA ENTRO al edit')
var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();

$("#id1").val(col1);
$("#id2").val(col2);
$("#id3").val(col3);   
}
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien me trae los valores del tr que selecciono, solo que si en la tabla tengo 2 registros me lanza el alert 2 veces con el valor

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar y ver que te retorna en tu consola del navegador.
Saludos.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.tablita3').on('click', '.btn-eliminar', function(){
      var id = this.value;
      var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 

               col0.push(this.value); 
               col1.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text()); 
               col2.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text()); 
               col3.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text()); 
               col4.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text()); 
               col5.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text()); 
               col6.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text()); 
               col7.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(8)").text()); 
               col8.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").text()); 
               col9.push(currentRow.find("td:eq(10)").text()); 
               console.log('\n ++>'+col8+'\n ++>'+col0+'\n ++>'+col1+'\n ++>'+col2+'\n ++>'+col3+'\n ++>'+col4+'\n ++>'+col5+'\n ++>'+col6+'\n ++>'+col7+'\n ++>'+col9);

    });
});`
```